# Invoking the __call__ method of a superclass

Tags: python, inheritance

http://code.google.com/p/python-hidden-markov/source/browse/trunk/Markov.py

Contains a class `HMM`, which inherits from `BayesianModel`, which is a new-style class. Each has a `__call__` method. `HMM`'s `__call__` method is meant to invoke BayesianModel's at line 227:

```
return super(HMM,self)(PriorProbs)
```

However, this fails with an exception

```
super(HMM,self)
```

is not callable.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to invoke the `__call__` method itself, explicitly:

```
return super(HMM, self).__call__(PriorProbs)
```

This applies to *any* hook that needs to call the overridden method on the superclass.

`super()` returns a proxy object, with a [`.__getattribute__()` method](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) that searches the super-class hierarchy for the attribute you are searching for. This proxy itself is not callable; it has no `__call__` method of it's own. *Only* when you explicitly look up the `__call__` method as an attribute of that proxy can python find the right implementation for you.