# Why does super() not implement __call__?

Tags: python, inheritance, super

Imagine the following situation in python 3 (I'm using 3.6):

```
class T(object):
    def __call__(self):
        return 5

class U(T):
    def __call__(self):
        return 10 + super()()

U()()
```

This results in `TypeError: 'super' object is not callable`.

Making it work requires `U`to be defined as follows:

```
class U(T):
    def __call__(self):
        return 10 + super().__call__()
```

Why does the first version not work?
I found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806593/calling-parents-call-method-within-class), but it doesn't answer this question. In fact, this question is also asked in a comment on the answer there.

Further reading about [what super() actually returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44725483/what-exactly-does-super-return-in-python-3) gives me the impression that the proxy returned by `super()` would have to implement `__call__` and forward to the correct `__call__` implementation. 
From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12342963/invoking-the-call-method-of-a-superclass), I get that the proxy object that is returned by `super()` only has a `__getattribute__` method that returns the correct function of whichever parent.

If I understand correctly, that means that the proxy would only need to implement the following thing to make `super()()` work:

```
def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        return self["__call__"](*args, **kwargs)  # not sure if self is already bound to the method, if not that needs to be handled
    except AttributeError as ae:
        raise TypeError("Super is not callable") from ae
```

So why does it not do that?

Comment: As Martijn states in the linked question, *"This applies to any hook that needs to call the overridden method on the superclass."* Per PEP-20 [*"Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules."*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: @jonrsharpe As to your first comment, it still works in Python 3, so it's still correct syntax if you want to make it backwards compatible. And it's an interesting question, I would imagine though that they made a choice to not build in `__call__` since it would be the odd one out as nothing else is.

Comment: @RunOrVeith according to your logic, `super` should also automagically call `__init__`  - IOW instead of  explicitely calling `super().__init__(arg, otherarg)` we should be able to just write `super(arg, otherarg)`. Which of course won't work since the `super` class needs to have it's own constructor and initializer...

Comment: Yeah, I get why it doesn't work for `__init__`. But for `__call__` it would work without any major hacks (in my opinion), or wouldn't it?

Comment: Implementing some subset of magic methods just produces inconsistent and confusing behavior.